# solving of equations by the Euler method in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I wrote this mini pseudo code that solves the equation using the Euler method:

```
    // y'= x^2 - 5y
    int n = 10; // count of steps
    double h = 0.5; // step
    double x = 0;
    double y = 1;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            y += h * (x * x - 5 * y);
            x += h;
        }
        write << y; //result
```

Now I am trying to write this in Prolog language

```
loop2(N,H,X,Y) :-
    N > 0,
    write(Y), nl,
    Y is Y + H * (X * X - 5 * Y),
    X is X + H,
    S is N - 1,
    loop2(S, H, X, Y).
```

Here I solved the example on a piece of paper and should get 62.5
[image]

But in Prolog my Output =

```
?- loop2(10, 0.5, 0, 1).
1
false.
```

Comment: Do keep in mind that logic programming is more like maths than like imperative programming. So when you write `X is X + H` you are asking when it is true that `x == x + h`. If `h` is zero then any `x` would be true, but for non-zero `h` then the statement is always false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`X is X + H` becomes `0 is 0 + 0.5` and it is not, so case closed as far as Prolog is concerned, it has found your logical code is `false`, and reports that to you. You did tell it to `writeln(Y)` before that, so you still see `1` while it was trying.

You need to use new variable names for the results of calculations like you have used `S is N - 1`, e.g. `Xnext is X + H`.

---

The way you have shaped the countdown, `S` will eventually become `0` and then `N > 0` will be false and the whole thing will fail then. You can probably get away with using this to `write` the values before it eventually fails, but a more normal way to end recursion is to have

```
loop2(0,_,_,_).
loop2(N,H,X,Y) :-
    ...
```

which says that when the call to `loop2` happens, the top one is found first, if the first position is 0, then it succeeds. That ends the recursion and the whole thing succeeds.